# Long delay before onConnectionStateChange after disconnecting Bluetooth LE Device

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth

In iOS, I have no problem detecting when my device has been disconnected or switched off. The second my Bluetooth LE device is switched off, the delegate method `bleDidDisconnect` is called within milliseconds.

On Android (at least with my Galaxy S4) `BluetoothGattCallback`'s `onConnectionStateChange` is sometimes called 15 seconds later, if at all.

One strategy I had was to read RSSI and interpret a poor/low/nonexistent signal as a disconnected device. Unfortunately until the device is recognized as disconnected, the last RSSI value keeps getting repeated.

My main question is whether or not this is normal? Is this specific to my phone? And is there a workaround? I can't find very much on the subject, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed this on Android too. Anytime the receiver is disconnected it takes between 5 to 15 seconds to send the disconnect notice and at times it's not sent at all. I've looked for some way to send it as soon as the device becomes disconnected but have not had any luck yet.

Comment: You guys found any reason for this ? or a solution ?

Comment: any solution to this